# Center-align text within DIV with "display: table-cell"

Tags: html, css

### Overview

I have an image with variable width aligned to the left, with text (having variable length) to the right of it.

I am trying to make the width of the right-most `div` element (containing the text) to fill the remaining width, centering the text both horizontally and vertically.

However, I cannot find a way to center align the text horizontally.

### Code

As you can see by the code below, the text will only be centered in the rightmost `div` when the length of text flows over one line - however, in many instances in my project, the code is much smaller (this example is just "Centered Text") and the text is left-aligned:

```html
<hr>
<div style="float:left; height: 75px;">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/rJD1cRy.png" style="margin:auto;display:block;">
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table; height: 75px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="font-style: italic; color: #777; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
      Centered Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be "display: table-cell"? You know that technically that should not be used for positioning **at all**. It's still meant for tabular data, even if it's for divs. BTW: there will always be problems with elements meant for a certain purpose used for another purpose, because the guys at G believe code should be semantically correct. Besides being right in this regard, they also happen to have a bit more than 50% of the market and don't seem like they're losing any in the near future...

Comment: Because I need the text of variable width (and thus number of lines) to be positioned central *vertically* as well as horizontally. Can't be done any other way

Comment: Of course it can be done.

Comment: Happy to see an example mate!

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzr9ctrj/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for centering the right-most div horizontally ,
adding `margin:0 auto` to the div should fix the issue:

```html
<hr>
<div style="float:left; height: 75px;">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/rJD1cRy.png" style="margin:auto;display:block;">
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table; height: 75px; overflow: hidden; margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="font-style: italic; color: #777; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
      Centered Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <hr>
<div style="float:left; height: 75px;">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/rJD1cRy.png" style="margin:auto;display:block;">
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table; height: 75px; overflow: hidden; width: 60%;">
    <div style="font-style: italic; color: rgb(119, 119, 119); display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
      Centered Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: It's close, but while the text does appear center-aligned, it is still much closer to the right than the left. [Example](http://i.imgur.com/jt5b0MZ.png)